# There is an empty message in terminal

Tags: python, discord.py

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAgTp.png
it aint see my message. There is just empty message
I upload my bot to discord and copy the token, but there ni message just empty

```
import discord
import random


TOKEN = "token is here"

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f"{username}: {user_message} ({channel})")


    if message.author == client.user:
    return

    if message.channel.name == "discord-bot-tutorial":
        if user_message.lower() == "hello":
            await message.channel.send(f"Hello {username}!")
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == "bye":
            await message.channel.send(f"See you next time!{username}!")
        elif user_message.lower() == "!random":
            response = f"This is your random number: {random.randrange(100000)}"
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return

    if user_message.lower() == "!anywhere":
        await message.channel.send(f"This can be anywhere")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most probable cause of this could be that the [Message Content Intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-content-intent) is turned off. Without it Discord will not send you content of the messages.
You can enable it on [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) under "Bot" tab.

You will also need to add this intent in your code like this:

```
# (edited)
intents = discord.Intents(message_content=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: TypeError: intents parameter must be Intent not <class 'discord.flags.flag_value'>

Comment: MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT
Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages.

NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and approval. Read more here
ON

Comment: This is not how you enable intents... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go

Comment: I added this intent to my code but it still empty